# Makefile findstring yields nonempty string even though the argument is not in the whitelist

Tags: makefile

I want my Makefile to require that an environment be specified, e.g.

```
make ENV=beta all
```

My Makefile begins like this

```
ifeq ($(findstring ${ENV}, dev beta prod),)
  $(error ENV must be dev, beta, or prod (e.g. make ENV=dev))
endif

nop:
    echo "Nothing done."$(findstring ${ENV}, dev beta prod)"#"
```

If I run

```
make ENV=devx nop
```

I get this output

```
Makefile:7: *** ENV must be dev, beta, or prod (e.g. make ENV=dev). Stop.
```

On the other hand

```
make ENV=d nop
```

gives this output

```
echo "Nothing done."d"#"
Nothing done.d#
```

This shows that `$(findstring...` is returning a non-empty string [contrary to the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)

What's the catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `findstring` function is finding an instance of "d"; the documentation is ambiguous, not incorrect. Use `filter` instead.